# I can't extend border on last child

Tags: html, css, nested-lists

I have created an organisational tree and I am lowering certain boxes to show "importance" of job roles and just general neatness. This works all fine but for some reason I can't seem to extend the border on the last child to match up with the box.

On my full tree (not the fiddle) I have multiple branches and they all extend perfectly except for the last right smaller branch on each bigger branch.

To extend the border i'm adding a class to each `<li>` like so:

> .finance li:after { height: 80px; border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
>   z-index:-999;}

I just can't understand why it works fine on all `<li>`'s except for the last ones.

I have reproduced the problem in this fiddle:

[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/V8H6T/17/)

[image]

---

**UPDATE:**

This is my full tree with the line problems: http://jsfiddle.net/HSwx4/

And here it is when I edit `.tree li:last-child::before`: http://jsfiddle.net/HSwx4/1/

Answer (score 2):

It's inheriting a height of 20px from your `.tree li::before, .tree li::after` selector. Change your `.tree li:last-child::before` selector to include a height of its own:

```
.tree li:last-child::before {
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 0px 0 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 0px 0 0;
    border-radius: 0 0px 0 0;
    height: 100%;
}
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/V8H6T/19/).

Comment: ah cool, that works but how would I apply that to multiple lines with different heights?

Comment: @Adsy it seems you can use `100%` instead of a fixed value. I've updated my answer. :)

Comment: This doesn't work when applied to my bigger tree. it adds some unwanted lines. is there no way I can add these to separate classes to edit individual lengths?

Comment: Could you please provide an updated JSFiddle which demonstrates this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out!

I added:

```
li .warehouse:last-child:after {top:20px;height: 290px !important; border-left: 2px solid #999 !important;}
```

I needed to add `!important` so it made sure it forced the border to appear because

`.tree li:first-child:before, .tree li:last-child:after{`

had

```
border: 0 none;
```